# ldapsearch entire active directory without refldap returns

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am trying to perform a filtered ldapsearch through the the entire AD. However, when I set the basedn to be the domain I get "refldap" referral responses from the query to the other 'partitions', even if the filter is not matched (which is what I want to test for...)

e.g.

```
   ldapsearch -LLL -h 127.0.0.1 -b "dc=ad-test,dc=local" -D "cn=ldapproxy,cn=users,DC=ad-test,DC=local" -w password (&(pwmResponseSet=*)(samaccountname=notestuser))" dn

# refldap://ForestDnsZones.ad-test.local/DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=ad-test,DC=local

# refldap://DomainDnsZones.ad-test.local/DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=ad-test,DC=local

# refldap://ad-test.local/CN=Configuration,DC=ad-test,DC=local
```

Is there a way to prevent these referral entries/returns?

(I'm trying to write the output to a flag file, which I then test for size... With the spurious entries I still get file size <> 0 even when the filtered query fails)

I did think about querying the GC, but the attribute I want is not stored there (and I don't want to add it!)

Any ideas?
Thanks
David

Comment: ... | egrep -v "^(# .*|)$" > yourfile.ldif

Answer (score 0):

I *think I've found an alternative that I can use. If I use the RSAT dsquery.exe tool in 'ldap mode'(https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754232.aspx) that seems to do the trick i.e.

```
dsquery * domainroot -filter "(&(pwmResponseSet=*)(samaccountname=%USERNAME%))"
```

I hope this helps someone in the same boat

Cheers
David

Answer (score 0):

If you have long lines that fold, it would be useful to prevent this by adding the following argument to the ldapsearch command:

```
-o ldif-wrap=no
```

If you are on a Windows version that permits it, you could then use `findstr`.

For example:

```
ldapsearch -o ldif-wrap=no -LLL -h 127.0.0.1 -b "dc=ad-test,dc=local" ^
    -D "cn=ldapproxy,cn=users,DC=ad-test,DC=local" ^
    -w password ^
    (&(pwmResponseSet=*)(samaccountname=notestuser))" dn | ^
    findstr /r /v /c:"^# refldap" /c:"^$" "%~1" > yourfile.ldif
```

Or if you want to do it on linux:

```
ldapsearch -o ldif-wrap=no -LLL -h 127.0.0.1 -b "dc=ad-test,dc=local" \
    -D "cn=ldapproxy,cn=users,DC=ad-test,DC=local" \
    -w password \
    (&(pwmResponseSet=*)(samaccountname=notestuser))" dn | \
    grep -v -e "^# refldap" -e "^$" > yourfile.ldif
```

This prevents line folding.

It also filters out all lines beginning exactly with `# refldap` string and empty lines.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** Don't leave any space after the `^` on windows or `\`
 on linux otherwise it won't work.
Hope it helps.